# Tensor products over operads and bar constructions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, operads

Let $O$ be an operad in spaces, $A$ an $O$-algebra and $R$ an right $O$-module. One can define $R \otimes_O A$ as the coequalizer of the two maps $ROA$ to $RA$. One can also define $B(R,O,A)$ (as in geometry of iterated loop spaces) to be the geometric realization of a simplicial space with space of $n$-simplicies given by $RO^nA$. Does anyone know a reference in the literature for sufficient conditions for when these two constructions yield weakly homotopy equivalent spaces?

Comment: It feels like if we have a notion that says the "difference" between the two maps $ROA \to RA$ is a cofibration, then under that condition $R \otimes_O A$ and $B(R,O,A)$ should be the same.

Comment: Hey, slow down and look at the "bar construction'' in the cited reference: O is a monad acting on the left on an algebra (or more generally on a functor out of some domain category) and on the right on a functor (such as the n-fold suspension when O is the little n-cubes operad).  I assume right module is meant in the sense of Fresse's book ``Modules over operads and functors'', but I don't see that as a functor with a right action by the monad O, so I don't see what bar construction you have in mind.

Comment: I believe that I mean the following. A symmetric sequence of spaces $Z$ gives a functor from spaces to spaces via the formula $ZX=\sqcup Z(i) \times_{S_i} X^i$. Here $Z(i)$ is the $i$th space, $S_i$ is the symmetric group on $i$ letters and $X$ is a space. I believe that a right module structure on a symmetric sequence is the same data as a right functor structure on the functor associated to the symmetric sequence. I think this should allow one to make sense of $B(R,O,A)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space $B(R,O,A)$ is the tensor product $B(R,O,O)\otimes_OA$. It is a standard fact that the right module $B(R,O,O)$ is cofibrant in the projective model structure of right modules whenever $R$ is levelwise cofibrant.

By Theorem 15.1.A.(a) of Fresse's "Modules over operads and functors", if $A$ is cofibrant (as a space) and $O$ is levelwise cofibrant, then the functor $-\otimes_OA$ preserves weak equivalences between cofibrant (in the projective model structure) right modules. In particular the two constructions you want to consider coincide up to weak equivalence if $R$ is cofibrant in the projective model structure.

Using Theorem 15.1.A.(b) of the same book, you can also show that the two constructions coincide up to weak equivalence if $A$ is cofibrant as an algebra, $O$ is levelwise cofibrant and $R$ is levelwise cofibrant.